# PHP If statement that on has variables

Tags: php, if-statement

i need help with this, currently my idea here is to only use variables to perform an IF statement, these variables are supposed to be taken from a database (ive got that down) but i dont know how to create an if statement that can use all 3

```
<?php
$Anum="10";
$Bnum="30";
$MOD="<=";

if ($Anum $MOD $Bnum)
{
echo $Anum, " is smaller than ", $Bnum;
}
else
{
echo "$Anum, " is not smaller than ", $Bnum;
}
?>
```

Comment: To use this form you must use http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php, it is not recommended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php

> `$MOD="<=";` will assign as a string (double quoted characters)

For assigning this as a comparison operator you have to do something like this

```
 <?php
    $Anum=10;
    $Bnum=30;
    $MOD=">=";
     switch ($MOD) {
            case '<=': if($Anum <= $Bnum){ echo $Anum ." is smaller than ". $Bnum;} else{ echo $Anum ." is not smaller than ". $Bnum; }; break;
            case '>=': if ($Anum >= $Bnum){ echo $Bnum ." is smaller than ". $Anum;} else{ echo $Bnum ." is not smaller than ". $Anum; }; break;
           }

    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! this will work too, appreciate your help :)

Comment: No Problem .Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you:

```
$Anum="10";
$Bnum="30";
$MOD=">=";

eval("\$result = ($Anum $MOD $Bnum) ? true : false;");

if ($result) {
    echo "$Anum is smaller than $Bnum";
} else {
    echo "$Anum is not smaller than $Bnum";
}
```

Output:

```
10 is not smaller than 30
```

**BUT.**

PHP has [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) and can expand strings into variables with it, but it does not work for language constructs, only for variables. ">=" is a comparison operator, so by this:

```
$Anum.$MOD.$Bnum
//or this
"$Anum $MOD $Bnum"
or this
"{$Anum} {$MOD} {$Bnum}"
```

You can only get a **string**, which will always give you `true` when using with `if` statement. To achieve what you want with your strategy you need to use [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). But it is a function, that should be avoided, unless you have enough experience and knowledge to use it with all responsibility and caution.

Comment: Yes this will work as he expected.What about my solution ?

Comment: @Sree a little verbose but will work for this case too.

Comment: Was sort of hoping to not use eval, but thank you all the same! i guess i will have to use this then.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$Anum="10";
$Bnum="30";
$MOD="<=";

$result = eval("if($Anum $MOD $Bnum){return true;}else{return false;}");

if ($result)
{
echo $Anum. " is smaller than ". $Bnum;
}
else
{
echo "$Anum, is not smaller than ". $Bnum;
}?>
```

here

> eval("if($Anum $MOD $Bnum){true}else{false}");

will execute the if condition and return the result and save it to some variable, and put this variable to if statment.

Comment: Did you run you code? Your `eval` statement won't run.